# Joomla Website not accessible using VPN

Tags: php, joomla

I have a Joomla site running on local intranet. It works perfectly if accessed via LAN. But if someone tries to access the same via VPN network then gives below error.

> Access to the Web site is blocked by your administrator. Please notify your system administrator. Made http request for GET /index.php?option=com_content&view=category&id=634:blackberry-&Itemid=59&layout=default HTTP/1.1 to techiecloud:80

What could be the possible reason for the same, Is it application configuration issue or related to network.

Comment: It looks like your VPN setup blocks port 80 requests to that box. You'll need to contact network support for your setup to have that restriction lifted.

Answer (score 0):

That's a network error message rather than a Joomla one.

Try uploading any website there - Joomla or not - and I assume you will get the same message.